# Does anyone know how to create this type of complex gradient background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient, gradient-mesh

I was looking online and found this really lovely photo of a gradient background, and I wanted to know how to replicate it for my own works, I tried different things, some being applying colors using a brush and applying a blur filter, the other using the gradient mesh tool in illustrator, neither gave me the look I desired so does anyone know how to achieve this type of background?

[image]

Comment: What about your attempts didn't work? It sounds like you were on the right track to me. Maybe [edit] to include a screenshot of your best effort would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an image with complex gradient?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113164/how-to-create-an-image-with-complex-gradient)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Made this in 2 minutes in Photoshop.
-Black background layer
-New layer on top
-Choose your blue color
-Select your brush tool and choose the soft edge round brush 
-Turn the flow and opacity way down (10% each), enable the airbrush option and start stacking the color.
-You may choose a lighter blue to get more highlights in the center of the blue
:)

Answer (score 1):

As @Ryan says, you were on the right track with gradient mesh, but they take a bit of figuring out. In the below image, the top one is the image from your question and below it is a version that I recreated with a gradient mesh. It's not exactly the same, but this only took a couple of minutes and could be made more similar with a bit of work. The bottom version shows the gradient mesh that I used. The two points that i have circled in red are set to the lightest colour in the background, all the other mesh points are set to the darker colour. After that it's just a case of moving the points and the handles around until you like what you see.

[image]