# How to create an image with complex gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, images, gradient

[image: example]

I need to create an image like this, but I do not know what software or technique to use. I tried to use the Mesh Tool in Illustrator, but the result is odd, also I tried to blur an image in Photoshop, but I need to use some particular colors.

Comment: Short answer is that you can make a layer with a stroke tool in photoshop, and blend that in with the background color. There is some 'manual' work to it, but I believe this to be an easy approach.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Using Photoshop

- Over a colored background, use the **Lasso Tool** to create an
  irregular selection
- With this selection make a **Color Fill Layer** with the dark color
- Click on the **Mask Thumbnail**
- **Menu Filter** > **Blur** > **Gaussian Blur**

[image: blur]

**Result**

[image: end]

Comment: Wow, that looks more like copy-paste!