# How can I make complex gradient images like these in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gradient, gradient-mesh

How can I create these types of gradient images in Photoshop or Illustrator?

I don't understand how they made these swooshes.

[image: Gradient]
[image: Gradient example I made]
Lower picture is what I came up with... but it's not the same.

Your help is much appreciated.

Greetings,
Pim

Answer (score 1):

My guess is using Illustrator's mesh tool, create a random grid and play with it (see Youtube videos), then blur the whole thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Illustrator use the mesh tool as Lucian say, you can move the vertex around. Try different grid density.

In Photoshop you can simply make some blotches of color and use the smudge tool. The trick is to test a different radius and pressures.

Danielillo pointed another method using a general Gaussian blur. [How to create an image with complex gradient?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113164/how-to-create-an-image-with-complex-gradient)